How to use filter condition and copy files from one blob storage to another blob storage in Azure Data Factory?
I am new to ADF. I create a pipeline that combines Get Metadata, Filter, and Foreach activities.
I want to get specific files with all kinds of formats,
for example:
ins01299.xml,
ins3391.xml, 
ins6991.pdf, 
AD3192.xml, 
TRMA1119.xml 
TRMA1119.pdf. 

Sometimes, I have a list of more than 100 files requested to be copied to other blob storage. What is the best approach to using the
Filter Activity Condition? it fails to use @or operator condition.

**Get Metadata Activity**
   Dataset: DatasetConnectInput
   Field list: Child items

**Filter Activity**
Setting: 
    Items: @activity('GetMetadata').output.childItems
    Condition: @or(
                or(equals(item().name, 'ins01299.xml'), equals(item().name, 'ins3391.xml')),
                or(equals(item().name, 'ins6991.pdf'),equals(item().name,'AD3192.xml')),
                or(equals(item().name, 'TRMA1119.xml'),equals(item().name,'TRMA1119.pdf')))

FAIL: function 'or' does not accept 3 argument(s)
**Foreach Activity**
Setting: 
    Items: @activity('Filter').output.value

Inside **Foreach** has a Copy Data Activity
    Source Dataset: DatasetConnectInput
    File path type: select "wildcard file path"
    wildcard paths: R40/ /@item().name
    
    Sink Dataset: DatasetConnectDestination



FAIL: function 'or' does not accept 3 argument(s)

or() function only supports 2 arguments or(expr1,expr2).
Modify the above expression like below where you need to make sure that every or() function is getting 2 arguments.
@or(
    or(
        or(
            equals(item().name, 'ins01299.xml'), equals(item().name, 'ins3391.xml')
            ),
        or(
            equals(item().name, 'ins6991.pdf'),equals(item().name,'AD3192.xml')
            )
        ),
    or(equals(item().name, 'TRMA1119.xml'),equals(item().name,'TRMA1119.pdf')))


(OR)
If the required file names are more, you can make a list of them and use contains(<your filenames array>,item().name) function with required file names array instead of or(). You can go through this SO answer to know more about it.
